# Autowiring problem with parameter injection in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm having troubles trying to retrieve a manager from a controller in Symfony 5.

I've got this MailerManager in `src/Manager/MailerManager.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Manager;

use App\Client\MailjetClient;

class MailerManager {
    private $mailjetClient;     

    function __construct(MailjetClient $mailjetClient) {
        $this->setMailjetClient($mailjetClient);        
    }

    function send($data) {

    }

    function getMailjetClient() {
        return $this->mailjetClient;
    }

    private function setMailjetClient($mailjetClient) {
        $this->mailjetClient = $mailjetClient;
    }

}
```

This manager needs to inject `src/Client/MailjetClient.php` in order to work, that has got this code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Client;

use \Mailjet\Resources;

class MailjetClient {
    private $client;    

    function __construct(string $apikey, string $apisecret) {                       
        $this->setClient($apikey, $apisecret);      
    }               

    function getClient() {
        return $this->client;
    }

    function setClient($apikey, $apisecret) {
        $this->client = new \Mailjet\Client($apikey, $apisecret);
    }
}
```

This is just a wrapper for the mailjet sdk installed via composer, that needs to be feeded with different `$apikey` and `$apisecret` depending on the environment, for what I'm using parameters through `services.yaml` file, where I also have got autowiring enabled and service definitions for both `MailjetClient` and `MailerManager`:

```
parameters:
    rabbitmq:
        host: '%env(RABBITMQ_HOST)%'
        port: '%env(RABBITMQ_PORT)%'
        user: '%env(RABBITMQ_USER)%'
        pwd: '%env(RABBITMQ_PWD)%'
    mailjet:
        apikey: '%env(MAILJET_APIKEY)%'
        apisecret: '%env(MAILJET_APISECRET)%'

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Client\MailjetClient\:
        resource: '../src/Client/MailjetClient.php'
        arguments:
            $apikey: '%mailjet.host%'
            $apisecret: '%mailjet.port%'        

    App\Manager\MailerManager\:
        resource: '../src/Manager/MailerManager.php'        
        arguments:
            $mailjetClient: '@client.mailjet'
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting this error: `Cannot autowire service "App\Client\MailjetClient": argument "$apikey" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.` when I try to inject the `MailManager` in the `src/Controller/MailerController.php` controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Manager\MailerManager;

class MailerController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/compose", name="compose")
     */
    public function compose(MailerManager $mailerManager) 
    {        
        dump($mailerManager);die();
        }
    }       
}
```

What could posibbly be wrong? I'm coming from Symfony 2, and this parameter injection was something standard that used to work like a charm, now I'm totally confused about how to mix the autowiring with the service manual definition.

Comment: Why does your service definition end with `\\`, e.g. `App\Manager\MailerManager\ `?

Comment: Because 
App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

loads all directories except excludes. you need to exclude your MailJet service for this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a total disaster on the `services.yml` side, thanks to u_mulder and Tejas Gosai hints I could finally put this to work. I had a few type errors on the parameters I was injecting, the `MailManager.php` specific declaration was not needed, and my client namespaces should not end with `\` ad u_mulder suggested.

Finally, with this `services.yml` it works:

```
parameters:
    rabbitmq.host: '%env(RABBITMQ_HOST)%'
    rabbitmq.port: '%env(RABBITMQ_PORT)%'
    rabbitmq.user: '%env(RABBITMQ_USER)%'
    rabbitmq.pwd: '%env(RABBITMQ_PWD)%'
    mailjet.apikey: '%env(MAILJET_APIKEY)%'
    mailjet.apisecret: '%env(MAILJET_APISECRET)%'
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
    App\Client\MailjetClient:        
        arguments:
            $apikey: '%mailjet.apikey%'
            $apisecret: '%mailjet.apisecret%'

    App\Client\RabbitClient:        
        arguments: ['%rabbitmq.host%','%rabbitmq.port%','%rabbitmq.user%','%rabbitmq.pwd%']
```

Comment: You have to bind the parameters to avoid having to declare the services manually like you did here. Check out https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service